# FtpWebRequest: create nested directories (local vs remote)

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftpwebrequest

**Objective:**

I want to make sure that FTP path exists before uploading files, if not ==> create it.

**Code I'm using:**

```
Dim ftpPath As String = "ftp://----------/ParentDir/SubFolder1/SubFolder2"
If Not FTPDirExists(ftpPath) Then
    CreateFTPDir(ftpPath)
End If
```

Where `CreateFTPDir` is:

```
Private Sub CreateFTPDir(DirPath As String)
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(DirPath)
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password")
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory
    request.Proxy = Nothing
    request.KeepAlive = True
    Try
        Dim resp As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now, when I test this code on my local FTP server (created using FileZilla), it creates the path no matter the number of nested directories.. **but** when I use it on the actual (remote) FTP server, it throws the following exception: `The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable` if the directories to create are more than one.

My **question** is why doesn't this problem occur with the local server? and do I have to create each *nested* directory separately on the remote server?

---

**Additional info + 2nd question:**

This is the `FTPDirExists` function I'm using (the best I could come up with after a lot of searching):

```
Private Function FTPDirExists(DirPath As String) As Boolean
    DirPath &= If(DirPath.EndsWith("/"), "", "/")
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(DirPath)
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password")
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
    request.Proxy = Nothing
    request.KeepAlive = True
    Try
        Using resp As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Return True
        End Using
    Catch ex As WebException
        Dim resp As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse)
        If resp.StatusCode = FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable Then
            Return False ' ==> Unfortunately will return false for other reasons (like no permission).
        Else
            Return False ' ==> Don't bother about this.
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

It's not 100% accurate as I referred in the comment above, so please let me know if you have a more accurate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use another function that creates each folder of the path separately:

```
Public Shared Sub CreatePath(RootPath As String, PathToCreate As String, Cred As NetworkCredential)
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest
    Dim subDirs As String() = PathToCreate.Split("/"c)
    Dim currentDir As String = If(RootPath.EndsWith("/"), RootPath.Substring(0, RootPath.Length - 1), RootPath)
    For Each subDir As String In subDirs
        currentDir &= "/" & subDir

        request = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(currentDir), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = Cred
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory
        request.Proxy = Nothing
        Try
            Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            response.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```